# mysql will not insert past fourth row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm not exactly sure what happened but this database and the php effecting it were working just fine until it hit the fourth row and now it won't insert new records at all.

```js
if($_POST)
{

   $servername = ******;
   $username   = ******;
   $password   = ******;
   $db         = ******;

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);


    mysqli_select_db($conn,$db);

    $uuid = $_POST['uuid'];



    $sql = "INSERT INTO uuid VALUES ('$uuid');";


    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

I'm not sure what happened but this is the relevant code for the mysqli query.

Comment: Try `mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` to show error if occurred

Comment: Kindly Include the table structure in the OP.

Comment: just for the record your `mysqli_select_db($conn,$db);` statement is not necessary as you have specified db while making connection

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['uuid']))
{

   $servername = yourServerName;
   $username   = username;
   $password   = password;
   $dbname     = databaseName;

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$uuid = $_POST['uuid'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tableName (columnName) VALUES ('$uuid')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

}
?>
```

Also, I recommend using prepared statements.